# Executable to library memory allocation

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I started from a executable A. This will be re-exported as a static library, which I will use in executable B.

Inside the source code for executable A I have a:

```
int a[100][100];
```

which is declared at a global level.

While running executable A `variable a` is on the heap (as expected) and the contents of the memory surrounding it is 0.

My questions is as follows:

Where is `variable a` going to be in when running executable B which links and uses variables from static library A (generated from executable A)?

Comment: *"variable `a` is on the heap (as expected) "* - No, that is not true. There is no heap involved here.

Comment: Ok. Where will variable a be located?

Comment: Why not just run A, and B, and have them both print the address? What are you trying to achieve, or understand?

Comment: A is an executable that does task C, I want task C to also be done in executable B while using a static library.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a[100][100];
```

a, being global, will be on global space, and in separate address space per executable, as these are statically linked, so, no common sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Variable a will be in the Data section of the program (not the heap, heap = dynamic memory).

In other words a will be in the same memory space as if you would run A by itself, and since it's a global variable it will end up in the data section of the program, together with other constants / static / global variables.

When you static link a library, the compiled code from that library is being "copy-pasted" into the new executable. So you're not in a situation where A is a separate process from B.

You have a B which uses code written from A.

Answer (score 0):

Each executable has its own process and memory space.  So Executable A will have your declared variable in it's stack and Executable B will have it's own copy of it in it's stack.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication for more info.